# Display word count / tag cloud in proportion

Tags: php, math

This is weird, so be patient while I try to explain.

Basic problem: I have a massive string -- it can be of varying lengths depending on the user. My job is to acquire this massive string depending on the user, then send it off to the other piece of software to make a tag cloud.  If life were easy for me, I could simply send the whole thing.  However, the tag cloud software will only accept a string that is 1000 words long, so I need to do some work on my string to send the most important words.

My first thought was to count each occurrence of the words, and throw all this into an array with each word's count, then sort.

```
array(517) (
    "We" => integer 4
    "Five" => integer 1
    "Ten's" => integer 1
    "best" => integer 2
    "climbing" => integer 3
     (etc...)
```

Form here, I create a new string and spit out each word times its count.  Once the total string hits 1000 words long, I stop. This creates a problem.

Let's say the word "apple" shows up 900 times, and the word "cat" shows up 100 times. The resulting word cloud would consist of only two words.

My idea is to somehow spit out the words at some sort of ratio to the other words.  My attempts so far have failed on different data sets where the ratio is not great -- especially when there are a lot of words at "1", thus making the GCD very low.

I figure this is a simple math problem I can't get my head around, so I turn to the oracle that is stackoverflow.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right, that's weird.  Can you define the problem more specifically, including all of the bounds (i.e. how many words in the original string) and possibly why you have to send a string to the other part of the software?  It seems to me that if you have at most 1000 words in the original string, you could send that string, and if you had more than 1000 words in the original string, you could end up with 1001+ unique words.  I'm guessing I don't understand the problem...

Comment: if I understand well your 1000 char string must include duplicates?

Comment: Yes -- this how the other piece of software determines the weighting for the tag cloud (it does its own word count based off the string I send it)

Comment: This is a limitation of your "cloud software", if you have more than 1000 words, then it'll be impossible to make an accurate cloud unless you decide to leave words out.

Comment: This is understood -- that's why i'm trying to start with the most populous words first.  Leaving out the lesser words is an acceptable outcome.

Comment: mathematically it is possible. you just have to reduce the wordcount by the right proportion as showed in my answer. BUT wordloss may be possible if you don't handle that.

Comment: +1 for this challenging question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

count all words then do this for each word in your array:

```
floor(count_of_the_word * (1000/numbber_of_total_words))
```

this will result in a maximum of 1000 words and all word appear in x times reduced by the according proportion.

so having 50 times cat 100 times gozilla 4000 looser and 4000 times bush 1000 times george will first result in

```
array(
    cat[50]
    gozilla[100]
    looser[4000]
    bush[4000]
    george[1000]
)
```

after looping and converting the numbers you will get this:

```
array(
    cat[5]
    gozilla[10]
    looser[437]
    bush[437]
    george[109]
)
```

resulting in 998 total words

Comment: if you want to totaly avoid the loss of words then just count how often you have a 0 after the transformation and reduce the biggest count by this number and add 1 to each word that has a 0 as a count